# Toggling an :active class with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm implementing an on-boarding screen in which the user selects 3+ items and after the user clicks it a purple overlay stays.

Like this: 
[image]

Here's my code:

```
var RepeatModule = React.createClass({
   getInitialState: function() {
      return { items: this.props.items || [] }
   },
   componentWillMount: function() {
     console.log("componentWillMount()")
     this.setState({ items : data })
     console.log(data,"data is here");
   },
   handleClick: function (e, item) {
    this.setState({active: true});
   },
   render: function() {
      var listItems = this.state.items.map(function(item) {
         return (
            <ListItem item={item}/>
         );
      });
      return (
         <div className="flex-container">
             {listItems}
         </div>
      );
   }
});
/* make the items stateless */
var ListItem = function(props) {
    var backgroundImage = {
      backgroundImage: 'url(' + props.item.pictureURL + ')'
    };
     return (
         <div className="block-grid-item">
          <a className="display-block card text-gray-darker">
            <div onClick={handleClick} style={backgroundImage} className="card-img-wrap m-xs-0 placeholder placeholder-landscape">
            </div>
            <div className="card-meta">
              <div className="vesta-hp-gifts-card-title text-gray-darker">{props.item.storeName}</div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
     );
}
```

I'm having trouble making the active state stay as I tried to do that in my handleClick function.

Here's my hover css effect

```
.card-img-wrap::after
  {
    background-color: #000;
    bottom: 0px;
    content: "";
    left: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
  }
  .card-img-wrap:hover::after
  {
    background-color: #000;
    bottom: 0px;
    content: "";
    left: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 0.6;
    background-color: #5450DC;
  }
```

**Why is this not working? How can this be done?**

Comment: You are not passing `handleClick` to `ListItem`. Even then, you are not keeping track of active items.

Comment: @xiaofan2406 how to pass handleClick to ListItem?

Answer (score 1):

You must pass the properties to ListItem, `handleClick` for example :

```
   render: function() {
      var listItems = this.state.items.map(function(item) {
         return (
            <ListItem handleClick={this.handleClick} item={item}/>
         );
      });
      return (
         <div className="flex-container">
             {listItems}
         </div>
      );
   }
```

and then it will be available under props in the `ListItem`

```
var ListItem = function(props) {
    var backgroundImage = {
      backgroundImage: 'url(' + props.item.pictureURL + ')'
    };
     return (
         <div className="block-grid-item">
          <a className="display-block card text-gray-darker">
            <div onClick={props.handleClick} style={backgroundImage} className="card-img-wrap m-xs-0 placeholder placeholder-landscape">
            </div>
            <div className="card-meta">
              <div className="vesta-hp-gifts-card-title text-gray-darker">{props.item.storeName}</div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
     );
}
```

The same you should to with the `active` prop, either control it within `ListItem` or pass it through props from parent (depend on your needs) and according to this prop you should add/remove the classNames.

jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/67316/

note that i am using there ES6 features in order to keep the context, you can use bind or other methods so this.handleClick will refer to the class function

Comment: Unfortunately, I am still getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleClick' of undefined

Comment: Trying to figure out. Why is this?

Comment: it is available under the props of ListItem. try using the props prop u passed to the constructor (instead of this.props) of ListItem or create ListItem with `React.createClass` as well, I've edited my answer

Comment: Looks like handleClick is still undefined in the ListItem

Comment: i added a jsFiddle